# Fetching info from JVM MBeans

Tags: java, jvm, jmx, mbeans

I was trying to fetch the below details for my monitoring application using JVM MBeans

```
    thread-states.blocked
    thread-states.waiting
    gc.ConcurrentMarkSweep.runs
    gc.ParNew.runs
    thread_count
    daemon_thread_count
    memory.heap_usage
    memory.non_heap_usage
```

I am able to fetch most of them except

```
    thread-states.blocked
    thread-states.waiting
    gc.ConcurrentMarkSweep.runs
    gc.ParNew.runs
```

Does anybody know what MBean and attribute can be used to collect these values?
PS: i have googled this before posting it here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
thread-states.blocked
thread-states.waiting
```

you can use [`getAllThreadIds()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/management/ThreadMXBean.html#getAllThreadIds%28%29) and get each Thread's information [`getThreadInfo()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/management/ThreadMXBean.html#getThreadInfo%28long%29) and filter based on the state

```
gc.ConcurrentMarkSweep.runs
gc.ParNew.runs
```

get [`getGarbageCollectorMXBeans()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/management/ManagementFactory.html#getGarbageCollectorMXBeans%28%29) filter them for CMS and ParNew and [`getCollectionCount()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/management/GarbageCollectorMXBean.html#getCollectionCount%28%29)